# Segfault with Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, docker, debugging, python3, segmentation-fault

Segfault but why? It only happens with debian:stretch+mysql.connector+tox and Python3.x. Reproducible from just a few lines:

```
FROM debian:stretch
RUN apt update -y && apt install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev gcc wget tox vim python-pip python3-pip
RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.9/Python-3.6.9.tgz
RUN tar xvf Python-3.6.9.tgz && cd Python-3.6.9 &&./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-shared --with-ssl --with-ensurepip=install && make -j8 && make altinstall
RUN mkdir /tox-test && echo "[tox]" >> /tox-test/tox.ini && echo "envlist = py36" >> /tox-test/tox.ini && echo "[testenv]" >> /tox-test/tox.ini && echo "deps=" >> /tox-test/tox.ini
RUN echo "  mysql-connector-python" >> /tox-test/tox.ini && echo "commands=python3.6 setup.py test" >> /tox-test/tox.ini
RUN mkdir /tox-test/tests && touch /tox-test/tests/__init__.py && echo "import faulthandler\nfaulthandler.enable()\nimport mysql.connector as mysql" >> /tox-test/tests/test_segfault.py
RUN echo "mysql.connect(host='localhost', user='joe', password='bloggs')" >> /tox-test/tests/test_segfault.py
RUN mkdir /tox-test/foo && echo "print('foo')" >> /tox-test/foo/foo.py
RUN echo "from setuptools import setup" >> /tox-test/setup.py && echo "setup( name='foo',version='1.0',description='A module',author='Niklas R.',author_email='foomail@foo.com',packages=['foo'],test_suite='tests',)" >> /tox-test/setup.py
RUN cd /tox-test && export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Python-3.6.9 && tox
```

The above generates a segfault. With Ubuntu and Debian Jessie it works or can be worked around. I could not understand why it happens with Stretch and I could not fix it. The segfault seems to be related to networking because if I write "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" then it doesn't crash. Please help me understand. My speculation is that the imports are shadowing or using some own versions of ssl or similar. It is quite far-fetched.  It is reproducible on Ubuntu as well and even weirder story is that on Ubuntu the segfault is fixed if I add to the python from `werkzeug.exceptions import BadRequestKeyError` without even using the import, only importing it without using it. If I replace the mysql-connector-python with PyMySQL then it works. So it must be something from the mysql-connector-python. There are similar bug reports about that connector: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=97220

If I change one string "localhost" and write instead "127.0.0.1" then there is no segfault anymore:

```
FROM debian:stretch
RUN apt update -y && apt install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev gcc wget tox vim python-pip python3-pip
RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.9/Python-3.6.9.tgz
RUN tar xvf Python-3.6.9.tgz && cd Python-3.6.9 &&./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-shared --with-ssl --with-ensurepip=install && make -j8 && make altinstall
RUN mkdir /tox-test && echo "[tox]" >> /tox-test/tox.ini && echo "envlist = py36" >> /tox-test/tox.ini && echo "[testenv]" >> /tox-test/tox.ini && echo "deps=" >> /tox-test/tox.ini
RUN echo "  mysql-connector-python" >> /tox-test/tox.ini && echo "commands=python3.6 setup.py test" >> /tox-test/tox.ini
RUN mkdir /tox-test/tests && touch /tox-test/tests/__init__.py && echo "import faulthandler\nfaulthandler.enable()\nimport mysql.connector as mysql" >> /tox-test/tests/test_segfault.py
RUN echo "mysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='joe', password='bloggs')" >> /tox-test/tests/test_segfault.py
RUN mkdir /tox-test/foo && echo "print('foo')" >> /tox-test/foo/foo.py
RUN echo "from setuptools import setup" >> /tox-test/setup.py && echo "setup( name='foo',version='1.0',description='A module',author='Niklas R.',author_email='foomail@foo.com',packages=['foo'],test_suite='tests',)" >> /tox-test/setup.py
RUN cd /tox-test && export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Python-3.6.9 && tox
```

Comment: is this used in a docker environment ?

Comment: @francoisP I can reproduce the segfault in a docker environment but it should be reproducible with native Debian Stretch and the same configuration as in the dockerfile.

Comment: Is "localhost" defined in your /etc/hosts file ? It might be a bug about the name resolution that when it's trying to read the hosts from that file , if it cannot resolve that , it might actually come up with a null pointer or something which can cause the segfault. I don't know . I just guess because you said " if I write "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" then it doesn't crash".

Comment: @ParsaMousavi Yes it is but it also segfaults for any other hostname. It is reproducible on Ubuntu as well but even weirder story is that on Ubuntu the segfault is fixed if I add to the python `from werkzeug.exceptions import BadRequestKeyError`

Comment: My speculation is that the imports are shadowing or using some own versions of ssl or similar. It is quite far-fetched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

at first, it looks like a socket issue but socket.gethostbyname(host_name) works.
after some digging, I find that the issue is isolated to "  mysql-connector-python"
if you change that to "  mysql-connector-python-rf" in your tox.ini the error is gone. that means somewhere in  mysql-connector-python it is unable to resolve dns to ip.